# Cutting Lemma in Discrete Geometry

Tags: discrete-geometry

I'm looking for a survey or a source for Cutting Lemma. I looked at Matusek's Discrete Geometry textbook, but it only proved Cutting Lemma for lines in $\mathbb{R}^2.$ I need to know the proof in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and other variations of Cutting Lemma.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Chazelle B, "Cuttings." *Handbook of Data Structures and Applications* (D. Mehta and S. Sahni, editors), chap. 25. 2005. [PDF download](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~chazelle/pubs/cuttings.pdf).

**Theorem 1.1**. Given a set $H$ of $n$ hyperplanes in $\mathbb{R}^d$, 
for any $0 < \epsilon < 1$, there exists an $\epsilon$-cutting for $H$
of size $O(\epsilon^{-d})$, which is optimal. The cutting, together with the
list of hyperplanes intersecting the interior of each simplex, can be found deterministically in $O(n \epsilon^{1-d})$ time.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's actually great. I was wondering if there are any other variations for Cutting Lemma? Like for Circles, Curves, ..?

Comment: @Megan: Matoušek mentions a cutting lemma for circles, using vertical decomposition. Matoušek, Jiří. *Lectures on discrete geometry*. Vol. 212. New York: Springer, 2002. p.72.

Comment: @Megan: For curves: Sharir, Micha, and Joshua Zahl. "Cutting algebraic curves into pseudo-segments and applications." *Journal of Combinatorial Theory*, Series A 150 (2017): 1-35. [arXiv version](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.07877).